# Requesting a .gz file then opening as a dataframe

Tags: python, api

Very new python user here. I have a link to a zipped data set (csv.gz) that I'm trying to get into python without first downloading to my desktop, unzipping, and uploading to github in order to use pd.read_csv. The link is of the form where I think I am meant to request it using requests? But I am getting a 403 status code. I can't tell if it's because I'm requesting it wrong, or if the .gz is the problem?

This is how I'm trying to import it.

```
import requests
query = {'AWSAccessKeyId':'theaccesskey', 'Signature':'thesignature','Expires':'12345'}
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/research.insideairbnb.com/data/united-states/or/portland/2015-12-02/data/listings.csv.gz'

response = requests.get(url, params=query)
```

But even assuming that I can figure out how to get a 200 status code, how do I go from .gz to dataframe that I can pandas with?

Comment: You could use `io.BytesIO` with `pandas.read_csv`. Interestingly, your url produces a JPEG image not a `.gz` file. Is it the right url / parameters?

Comment: I put in dummy parameters

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `io.BytesIO` with `pandas.read_csv`:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://github.com/apache-superset/examples-data/blob/master/san_francisco.csv.gz'

# This is required to access raw binary files on Github
# i.e. it appends the following to the URL: `?raw=true`.
query = {'raw': 'true'} 

# Use the requests module to parse the URL with the provided parameters.
response = requests.get(url, params=query)

# Create a file pointer initialized to the content of the response
# using `BytesIO`. This is a psuedo-file, which can now be read
# using `pandas.read_csv`. Since `response.content` is binary data
# i.e. bytes, we use `BytesIO`. If the response was text, we would
# have used `StringIO`.
fp = BytesIO(response.content)

# Finally, parse the content into a DataFrame 
# (populate other parameters as needed).
df = pd.read_csv(fp, compression='gzip')
print(df)
```

This should return the contents of the `csv.gz` file as a DataFrame. Using the URL in this example yields the following output:

```
               LON        LAT NUMBER            STREET UNIT  CITY  DISTRICT  REGION  POSTCODE  ID
0      -122.391267  37.769093   1550       04th Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94158 NaN
1      -122.390850  37.769426   1505       04th Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94158 NaN
2      -122.428577  37.780627   1160   Buchanan Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94115 NaN
3      -122.428534  37.780385   1142   Buchanan Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94115 NaN
4      -122.428525  37.780317   1140   Buchanan Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94115 NaN
...            ...        ...    ...               ...  ...   ...       ...     ...       ...  ..
261547 -122.418380  37.808349    360  Jefferson Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94133 NaN
261548 -122.418380  37.808349    350  Jefferson Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94133 NaN
261549 -122.417829  37.807479    333  Jefferson Street  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94133 NaN
261550 -122.418916  37.809044   1965      Al Scoma Way  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94133 NaN
261551 -122.444322  37.749124    350    Glenview Drive  NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     94131 NaN
```

I used a sample csv.gz file I found online as the URL and parameters yield a JPEG image instead which is a bit puzzling. In any case, adapt this snippet of code to your case, and it should produce the desired results.

Comment: @MargotBlack No prob! I think some specific headers are required as the link you shared works from the browser, curl, and wget - the file can be downloaded in isolation. However, with the requests library it yields a 403. I did a cursory search on applying common headers (e.g. `headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}`) to the request, but my attempts to apply them didn't yield any fruit. Also, you may want to remove or invalidate your access key ID and related credential since that could be abused